# .net core 1.0.1 mstests Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, mstest, .net-core

When I try to run my tests with Team Services, I get the following error

```
2016-09-16T11:01:12.0816791Z The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was not found.
2016-09-16T11:01:12.0826785Z   - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
2016-09-16T11:01:12.0826785Z       C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
2016-09-16T11:01:12.0826785Z   - The following versions are installed:
2016-09-16T11:01:12.0836784Z       1.0.0
2016-09-16T11:01:12.0836784Z       1.0.0-rc2-3002702
2016-09-16T11:01:12.0846787Z   - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.1'.
2016-09-16T11:01:12.0846787Z SUMMARY: Total: 1 targets, Passed: 0, Failed: 1.
```

I presume I just wait until tfsonline catches up.. or is there anything I can do to use some sort of preview tfsonline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using hosted build agent. According to [Software on the hosted build server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software-on-the-hosted-build-server), the hosted build server is deployed with the following .NET Framework:

- .NET 4.6
- .NET 4.5.2
- .NET 4.5.1
- .NET 4.5
- .NET 3.5 SP1
- .NET Core 1.0 with Preview 2 Tooling

You may try to deploy an on-premises build agent and install .NET Core 1.0.1 to work with VSTS: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/index#deploy_agent.

If you insist on using hosted build agent, then you need to use version 1.0.0-rc2-3002702 of Microsoft.NETCore.App, for example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
        "type": "platform"
    },
```

Comment: That's a good link, I presume that in time it will get updated.